# dependency error in C

Tags: c, dependencies, runtime-error

In my program, I am getting this runtime (compiler doesn't complain) error:
"undefined symbol xyz".

the lib that exercise this code is lib A. 
xyz is defined in lib B.

Can I derive any conclusion from this error? 
How should my dependencies look like for this to work? 
lib A should come after lib B ?

Or I am completely out of my mind ??

## Rephrasing my question:

If I make changes (solely changing dependencies) to a working program and now that program gives runtime error: "undefined symbol xyz", can I conclude anything from this error?

My motive is to understand how to interpret the error message and what to infer from it. It is fine if I cannot solve the issue.

Comment: Does the linker complain? Do you have warnings cranked all the way up? What does the code that produces the error look like?

Comment: you probably mean 'link time', not 'runtime'. But as nmichaels said: hard to give an answer without code and compiler/linker settings

Comment: I don't see any way that is a runtime error.   Also, if you want to discuss compilers, settings, and error messages, please tell us which compiler / OS / hardware you're running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a link-time error as the commenters suggest, then the only thing you can infer without any more info is that the linker sees a reference to an symbol called `xyz` in one file, but does not see that symbol defined in any of the object or lib files provided to it.

It is virtually impossible to tell why this happens without more information.  Some possibilities based on what you have said.

1. the set of files provided  to the linker does not include lib B
2. 'xyz' does not really exist in lib B.
3. 'xyz' is defined as static (no external linkage) in lib B.
4. lib B is a c++ library with name mangling turned on.
5. ???